How is memory handled for intermidiate values in Python?
For example, if you need to construct a new object from 2 lists, it seems that it is irrelevant whether you concat them and then iterate, or you yield from one list and then the other, even though intuitively concat should allocate more memory for that temporary value.
from itertools import pairwise, chain

from random import choice
from string import ascii_lowercase
import tracemalloc


def measure_allocation():
    s = [choice(ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(1_000_000)]
    
    tracemalloc.start()
    # HERE
    res1 = tuple(['^']+s)
    snapshot1 = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
    top_stats = snapshot1.statistics('lineno')
    for stat in top_stats[:10]:
        print(stat)

    tracemalloc.stop()
    print('*'*80)
    
    tracemalloc.start()
    # AND HERE
    res2 = tuple(chain(['^'],s))
    snapshot2 = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()

    top_stats = snapshot2.statistics('lineno')
    for stat in top_stats[:10]:
        print(stat)
    
    tracemalloc.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    print(sys.version)
    print('*'*80)
    
    measure_allocation()

Result:
3.12.6 (main, Sep  6 2024, 19:03:47) [GCC 13.3.0]
********************************************************************************
/tmp/tmp.MbQI2VsYCZ/foo.py:13: size=7813 KiB, count=1, average=7813 KiB
********************************************************************************
/tmp/tmp.MbQI2VsYCZ/foo.py:24: size=7813 KiB, count=1, average=7813 KiB

As you can see, both values are identical. Perhaps I am testing it incorrectly?
Just to clarify on why this is unexpected for me, the way I see it, python would for res1:

Evaluate the inner expression first (["^"] + s)
Make a new list in memory, which would be the same size as s since list sizes are increased in growing chunks.
At this point we have both s and the temp list in memory, so memory usage should be doubled
Now we iterate and construct the tuple, temp gets discarded.

Results however suggested that we only had to malloc for the tuple, not the intermediate list.

You understand that temp gets discarded, so why do you expect it to remain allocated?

@nocomment Even if it gets discarded, it has to first be allocated in order to be discarded, how can I observe if it does indeed get allocated? I have tried other memory profilers as well, but it doesn't show the allocation. That is why I suspect it actually never gets allocated at all and some other magic is going on.

@chrslg @nocomment I have modified the code to be simply: tc.start(); tc.reset_peak(); res1 = ...; print(tc.get_traced_memory()); tc.stop() and also for res2, and now indeed I am able to see the difference! I must have also used memory_profile incorrectly as well. The results now are exactly what I expected:
(8000048, 16000056) vs (8000048, 8651136) where the tuple represents (current, peak).

Actually, in your first scenario there, there is this overallocation, but it only takes place when executing this expression:res1 = tuple(['^']+s)
As you keep no references to the list which is created temporarily inside the tuple(...) call, when that call returns, that temporary list is immediately deallocated - even before the returned tuple is assigned to the res1 name.
So, even though you measure the memory in the very next line of code - that temporary list is already gone.
Let's take a look here, with the Python disassembler:
In [7]: def func():
   ...:     x = tuple(list(range(10_000_000)))
   ...:     return x
   ...: 

In [8]: dis.dis(func)
  1           RESUME                   0

  2           LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (tuple + NULL)
              LOAD_GLOBAL              3 (list + NULL)
              LOAD_GLOBAL              5 (range + NULL)
              LOAD_CONST               1 (10000000)
              CALL                     1
              CALL                     1
              CALL                     1
              STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  3           LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              RETURN_VALUE


Here the temporary list is returned by the second CALL operator - at this point it is on the operand stack. The third CALL operator will run tuple and the single reference to it is still on the operand stack. When the 3rd CALL resolves, the value on the stack is used inside the target callable (tuple) - when that is over (even if the tuple callable body temporarily creates another hard reference to the tmp list, it will free that before returning) , the operand stack is popped, and its reference count goes to zero, causing it to immediately deallocate itself, before the STORE_FAST opcode runs.
